# Sublime Text 3 snippet keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

I've been trying to create a shortcut to the snippet palette in Sublime Text 3 but can't seem to get it to work. I don't get an error, I just get nothing. I am on a Mac and have the following in *Preferences: Key Bindings - User*

```
{
    "keys": [ "ctrl+y" ],
    "command": "show_overlay",
    "args": {
        "overlay": "command_palette",
        "text": "Snippet:"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your code into this `[]` ?

It works for me:

```
[
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+y"], 
        "command": "show_overlay", 
        "args": {
            "overlay": "command_palette", 
            "text": "Snippet: "
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I did not. That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: If it works then you should accept my answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you.